# If $y = \alpha x + b$, what does it really mean that $b$ is statistically dependent with $x$ but uncorrelated?

Tags: probability, independence, covariance-matrix, cross-correlation

I have received a model from my teacher (they are random complex-valued vectors):

$$y = \alpha x + b,$$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is a deterministic scalar, $x,y,b \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

My teacher states that

> $b$ is *uncorrelated* with $x$ but *statistically dependent*.
>
> What does this mean mathematically and intuitively?

I am sorry for clarifying basic probability theory.

---

My understanding so far. Is it correct?

- Uncorrelated means that their cross-covariance matrix is zero, i.e., $\mathbb{E}\left\{ \left( x - \mu_x \right) \left( b - \mu_b \right)^* \right\} = 0$, where $\mu_x$ and $\mu_b$ are their respective means?
- Statistically dependent would mean that $\Pr\left( b | x \right) \neq \Pr\left( b\right)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both your points are correct. Uncorrelated means zero-covariance, while independence is a stronger condition and concern the joint distribution. If two random vectors are independent, we have the joint faxtorized with marginals, i.e. $P(x,b)=P(x)P(b)$ (converse is true also) which boils down to what you wrote as $$P(b|x)=\frac{P(b,x)}{P(x)}=\frac{P(b)P(x)}{P(x)}=P(b)$$

Consider the case where you have zero-correlation. It doesn't even mean that $E[b|x]=E[b]$. So, even if you have *no correlation*, you conditional mean for $b$ can *use* the information inside if $x$ is given.

But, $P(b|x)=P(b)$ guarantees that you have $E[b|x]=E[b]$ (and any other conditional moment if exists) because in the expected value integral/summation you'll substitute $P(b)$ instead of $P(b|x)$ and the equation will be exactly like $E[X]$.

Comment: thank you for the clarification.